# Creating an object array based on the contents of a file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a text file that looks like this.

> BEGINNING OF LIST
>   
>   Name: Janet
>   Age: 21
>   Birthday month: April
>   
>   END OF LIST
>   
>   BEGINNING OF LIST
>   
>   Name: Peter
>   Age: 34
>   Birthday month: January
>   
>   END OF LIST

So I want to grab info and put it into an object array. it is an extensive list and I am using the delimiters `beginning of list` and `end of list` to delimit the content.

How can I store these items in an object array?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this task? Don't yiu know how to read files? Or how to parse a string? Or how to create lists? Or how to create a model class?

Comment: I can read the files and create a model class. I just need to know how to separate it based on "THE BEGINNING OF LIST" and "END OF THE LIST" there is going to be a lot of useless info being read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create a class first for storing the information, with `name`, `age`, and `birthday month` attributes. It's a very good practice to override the `toString()` method so you can print out the class neatly.

Then you can check for each line whether it contains information about the name, age, or birthday month through splitting each line into an array of words, and checking for the information.

Once the line reads "END OF LIST", you can add a  `class Person` with the parameters to the `ArrayList`.

For the example I used *"people.txt"* as the file (make sure you place the text document outside of the *src* folder which  contains your .java files).

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        String name = null;
        String age = null;
        String month = null;
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        try
        {
            String fileName = "people.txt";
            fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = null;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] information = line.split(" ");

                if (Arrays.asList(information).contains("Name:"))
                {
                    name = information[1];
                }
                if (Arrays.asList(information).contains("Age:"))
                {
                    age = information[1];
                }
                if (Arrays.asList(information).contains("month:"))
                {
                    month = information[2];
                }
                if (line.equals("END OF LIST"))
                {
                    people.add(new Person(name, age, month));

                    name = "";
                    age = "";
                    month = "";
                }
            }

            for (Person person : people)
            {
                System.out.println(person);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading people.txt");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bufferedReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (fileReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileReader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String birthday;

    public Person(String name, String age, String birthday)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String information = "Name: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + "\nBirthday: " + birthday;
        return information;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SantanaMax Your welcome! If you think my answer is good, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: thanks. Just a quick question. If the "line" is null, then why do we split it up using spaces and how can I also delimit using "BEGINNING OF LIST" There is going to be a lot of useless info in between the lists.

Comment: @SantanaMax line is set to null at the beginning because we haven't read anything yet. We read the lines in the while loop so it isn't null when we start the file operation. The program I gave you actually ignores all the useless information between the list because it checks if the line actually contains information or not.

Comment: Ok thanks! Sorry I am a beginner so I am trying hard to understand